# How to update load context variable after change in django template via AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

My Table Items in page `customer_items.html`:

```
<table id="tblData" style="width: 100% !important;"
       class="display table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="display: none">Item ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Supplier Code</th>
        <th>Location Code</th>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Part Group</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th style="display: none">Location ID</th>
        <th style="display: none">Currency ID</th>
        <th style="display: none;">Line ID</th>
        <th style="display: none;">UOM</th>
        <th style="display: none;">Supplier ID</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% if items_list %}
        <tbody>
        {% for i in items_list %}
            <tr class="gradeX" id="{{ i.line_id }}">
                <td style="text-align: right; display: none;">{{ i.item_id }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left">{{ i.item_name }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left">{{ i.supplier_code }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left">{{ i.location_code }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left">{{ i.part_no }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">{{ i.part_gp }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left">{{ i.sales_price }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">{{ i.currency }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; display: none;">{{ i.location_id }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; display: none">{{ i.currency_id }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; display: none">{{ i.line_id }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; display: none">{{ i.uom }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right; display: none">{{ i.supplier_id }}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="choices"
                           id="{{ i.line_id }}"
                           class="call-checkbox"
                           value="{{ i.sales_price }}"></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    {% endif %}
</table>
```

In my main page, I include the customer items page inside it:

```
<div class="adv-table" id="myTable">
   {% include 'customer_items.html' %}
</div>
```

I used ajax to update items_list after change customer event run:

```
function customer_items(hdCustomerId) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/orders/change_customer_items/',
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                'customer_id': hdCustomerId,
            },
            responseTime: 200,
            response: function (settings) {
                if (settings.data.value) {
                    this.responseText = '{"success": true}';
                } else {
                    this.responseText = '{"success": false, "msg": "required"}';
                }
            },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
                $('#myTable').html('').load(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I change customer the table still empty although the new items_list has data.

```
views.py:
def customer_items(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            customer_id = request.POST.get('customer_id')
            items_list = CustomerItem.objects.filter(customer_id=customer_id).values() \
                .annotate(supplier_code=F('item__supplieritem__supplier__code')) \
                .annotate(supplier_id=F('item__supplieritem__supplier')) \
                .annotate(location_code=F('customer__company__location__code')) \
                .annotate(location_id=F('customer__company__location__id')) \
                .annotate(custome_name=F('customer__name')) \
                .annotate(item_id=F('item_id')) \
                .annotate(item_name=F('item__name')) \
                .annotate(part_no=F('item__part_no')) \
                .annotate(part_gp=F('item__part_gp')) \
                .annotate(uom=F('item__sales_measure__name')) \
                .annotate(currency=F('currency__code')) \
                .annotate(currency_id=F('currency_id')) \
                .annotate(line_id=Value(0, output_field=models.CharField()))
            for i, j in enumerate(items_list):
                if (i < items_list.__len__()):
                    i += 1
                    j['line_id'] = i
        return render(request, 'customer_items.html', {'items_list': items_list})
urls.py:
url(r'^change_customer_items/$', views.customer_items, name='change_customer_items'),
```

How can I run the load function after the ajax call successfully in the ajax to fill data to my table. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax function,

use `$('#myTable').html(data);` instead of `$('#myTable').html('').load(data);`

`.load()` is used for loading files but here you have source code. ;)